# Rails group by column and select column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, group-by

I have a table DinnerItem with columns id, name, project_id, client_id, item_id and item_quantity.

I want to fetch data group_by item_id column and the value should only have the item_quantity column value in the format

```
{ item_id1 => [ {item_quantity from row1}, {item_quantity from row2}],
  item_id2 => [ {item_quantity from row3}, {item_quantity from row4} ]
}
```

How can I achieve it in one single query?

```
OfferServiceModels::DinnerItem.all.select('item_id, item_quantity').group_by(&:item_id)
```

But this has the format

```
 {1=>[#<DinnerItem id: nil, item_id: 1, item_quantity: nil>, #<DinnerItem id: nil, item_id: 1, item_quantity: {"50"=>30, "100"=>10}>], 4=>[#<DinnerItem id: nil, item_id: 4, item_quantity: {"100"=>5, "1000"=>2}>}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```rb
result = OfferServiceModels::DinnerItem
  .pluck(:item_id, :item_quantity)
  .group_by(&:shift)
  .transform_values(&:flatten)
#=> {1 => [10, 20], 2 => [30, 40]}
#    ^ item id            ^^  ^^ item quantity
```

A step by step explanation:

```rb
# retrieve the item_id and item_quantity for each record
result = OfferServiceModels::DinnerItem.pluck(:item_id, :item_quantity)
#=> [[1, 10] [1, 20], [2, 30], [2, 40]]
#     ^ item id           ^^ item quantity

# group the records by item id, removing the item id from the array
result = result.group_by(&:shift)
#=> {1 => [[10], [20]], 2 => [[30], [40]]}
#    ^ item id                 ^^    ^^ item quantity

# flatten the groups since we don't want double nested arrays
result = result.transform_values(&:flatten)
#=> {1 => [10, 20], 2 => [30, 40]}
#    ^ item id            ^^  ^^ item quantity
```

**references:**

- [`pluck`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck)
- [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)
- [`shift`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-shift)
- [`transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values)
- [`flatten`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-flatten)

Comment: This is the perfect solution for grouping by a column after a `joins`

Answer (score 3):

You can keep the query and the grouping, but append `as_json` to the operation:

```
DinnerItem.select(:item_id, :item_quantity).group_by(&:item_id).as_json
# {"1"=>[{"id"=>nil, "item_id"=>1, "item_quantity"=>1}, {"id"=>nil, "item_id"=>1, "item_quantity"=>2}],
#  "2"=>[{"id"=>nil, "item_id"=>2, "item_quantity"=>1}, {"id"=>nil, "item_id"=>2, "item_quantity"=>2}]}
```

Notice as_json will add the id of each row which will have a nil value.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that this is possible without transforming the value returned from the db. If you are able to transform this, the following should work to give you the desired format:

```
OfferServiceModels::DinnerItem.all.select('item_id, item_quantity').group_by(&:item_id)
                              .transform_values { |vals| vals.map(&:item_quantity) }
# => {"1"=>[nil,{"50"=>30, "100"=>10}],"4"=>...}

# or

OfferServiceModels::DinnerItem.all.select('item_id, item_quantity').group_by(&:item_id)
                              .transform_values { |vals| vals.map { |val| val.slice(:item_quantity) }
 # => {"1"=>[{:item_quantity=>nil},:item_quantity=>{"50"=>30, "100"=>10}}],"4"=>...}
```

I'd argue there's nothing wrong with the output you're receiving straight from the db though. The data is there, so output the relevant field when needed: either through a transformation like above or when iterating through the data.

Hope this helps in some way, let me know :)